# Left Column fixed width, height of the right column; Right column fluid width

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a two column site, the left column is a fixed width, but it's the height I am struggling with. The height should either be the height of the window or the height of the right hand column (whichever is taller).

With my current solution, when the right column is taller than the browser window and you scroll down, the left column is chopped off.

## HTML

```
<div class="side-container">
  <!-- left side -->
  <aside>Left: Fixed width, 100% height of the window or right hand content</aside>
  <!--
  main content -->
  <article>Right: Fluid width</article>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.side-container {
  height:100%;
}
.side-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 200px;
  background: rgb(202, 147, 147);
}
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
article {
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/t3AxY/)

Comment: consider using Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
They have solution for Your layout.

Comment: Thanks @NikolaNinkovic I will take a look at how they did it. I don't really want to use a whole framework for just this reason though.

Comment: Well, I was just like You, before discovering Bootstrap...:)
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

Comment: @NikolaNinkovic Bootstrap doesn't seem to do what I'm asking in the main question. column height for the left column is not 100% of the browser

Answer (score 0):

All you really needed was to use `min-height` instead of `height` in some places:

http://jsfiddle.net/t3AxY/3/

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.side-container{
    min-height:100%;
    }

.side-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 200px;
    background: rgb(202, 147, 147);
    }

aside{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

article {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    }
```

Comment: that jsfiddle doesn't work for me, the left hand grey column is not 100% the height of the window. Is it working for you?

Comment: Odd, it does for me (Opera).  I don't typically run into situations where Opera works, but Chrome/Firefox/etc. don't.  Here's an alternate solution that also appears to only have the desired appearance in Opera:  http://jsfiddle.net/t3AxY/1/